# React Native Camera View

Tags: android, android-camera, react-native, react-native-camera

Question regarding using React Native. Is it possible to develop an app where it will record a video only without a camera view? Basically, an app that is just a video recorder without a monitor to see what the camera is seeing. If yes, I would appreciate if you can share a little bit of an idea on how to go about it.

Hiding it from the phone's viewing area whether by position, or giving it a width or height of 0, or making it transparent are not the kind of solutions that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a module from RN in JavaScript that would allow you to do that, then I believe that module is not around. At least in the official framework.

What you could do, is to create a NativeModule. RN allows you to actually execute native code from Android and iOS and then communicate through a bridge.

You can see how to create this modules here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html